# How do I create global variables using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have two different PowerShell scripts. Both of these scripts will execute sequentially with different sessions. The first PowerShell script should create a global variable and hold some value. The second script should read that global variable.

How do I create such a global variable in the first script?

Comment: Can your process not be refactored to just have the first script call the second?  Then it can pass in whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a global variable is easy. Just do
`$Global:yourvariable` when you are declaring it for the first time. After that, you can call that variable from anywhere by just using `$yourvariable`.

But I am afraid this is not is going to solve your problem, since you are trying to run two scripts separately on two different sessions. How can you be even sure that the first script will generate the 'global variable' before the second script asks for it?

If you are keen on running them in parallel, look up the `Start-Job` cmdlet or PowerShell Runspaces.

Another thing you can try is write the global variable out to a database or file that is accessible by both scripts. Using files could cause ownership deadlocks or "File is in use by another process" or other I/O errors.

What you are trying to do, simply cannot be done with global variables. That is why they are called sessions. One is independent of the other. But I am sure, whatever it is you are trying to do, can be achieved in simpler ways.

Answer (score 0):

Do they run at the same time?

If not, you're probably better off using [Export-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) to export the variable/object from one script and then use [Import-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Clixml) to import it into the other script.

In the first script:

```
$someVar | Export-Clixml C:\temp\someVar.xml
```

In the second script:

```
$someVar = Import-Clixml C:\temp\someVar.xml
```